# which php sort to use for multi dimensional array and by value 'price'?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

An example of the type of results for a API call are below.  I want to sort these results by price and keep the structure of the array.  I have tried numerous examples from the manual and also code I've found but can't seem to get the right combo to make it work. I would really appreciate any help.

```
array(7) { 
  ["errors"]=> array(0) { } 
  ["warnings"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
      ["code"]=> string(26) "api_class_update_available" 
      ["msg"]=> string(58) "The Api class is now available in version 1.6" 
    } 
  } 
  ["data"]=> array(4) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
      ["url"]=> string(7) "http://" 
      ["keyword"]=> string(7) "keyword1"  
      ["price"]=> string(5) "23.99" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
      ["url"]=> string(7) "http://" 
      ["keyword"]=> string(7) "keyword2"  
      ["price"]=> string(5) "19.99" 
    }  
    [2]=> array(3) { 
      ["url"]=> string(7) "http://" 
      ["keyword"]=> string(7) "keyword3"  
      ["price"]=> string(5) "29.99" 
    } 
    [3]=> array(3) { 
      ["url"]=> string(7) "http://" 
      ["keyword"]=> string(7) "keyword4"  
      ["price"]=> string(5) "9.99" 
    } 
  }
  ["countryCode"] => string(2) "US" 
  ["page"] => int(1) 
  ["limit"]=> int(4) 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) to sort the `$array['data']` property

```
function priceCompare($a, $b) { return $a['price'] - $b['price']; }
usort($results['data'], 'priceCompare');
```

Or in PHP 5.3, you can use a closure so you don't need to define a function:

```
usort($results['data'], function($a, $b) { return $a['price'] - $b['price']; });
```

Comment: brilliant! Thanks a ton gnarf!! PHP 5.2.14 was install, so the first example worked flawlessly!